# Выделение кривой области WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Здравствуйте, есть карта страны(изображение). Нужно обработать клик по областям. Никогда не работал на WPF, по координатам получится криво, уже пробовал, что можно еще сделать?
Нужно обработать клик по области, ну и при наведении мыши на область подсветку границы области.

```
<Image Height="204" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,21,0,0" Name="image2" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="352" Source="/Belarus;component/Images/3.png" ImageFailed="image2_ImageFailed" MouseUp="Clicked" />

    private void Clicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        //string pos = "X - " + e.GetPosition(this).X + " Y - " + e.GetPosition(this).Y;
        //MessageBox.Show(pos);
        //if (e.GetPosition(this).X >= 232 && e.GetPosition(this).X <= 566 &&
            //e.GetPosition(this).Y >= 27 && e.GetPosition(this).Y <= 147)
        //MessageBox.Show(e.Source.ToString());
    }
```

все что у меня есть

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этого можно добиться, хотя и не совсем просто.

Для начала, вам нужно получить картинки каждой из областей. Обратитесь за этим к вашему граф. дизайнеру. На картинке должна быть только область, а остальное обязано быть транспарентным.

Теперь, нам нужно определить клик на нетранспарентной области. Для этого проще всего использовать специализированный контрол, и переопределить hit testing.
Тогда мы сможем воспользоваться встроенными в WPF процедурами.

Наследуемся от `Image`:

```
public class OpaqueClickableImage : Image
{
    static int transparentAlpha = 128;

    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
    {
        if (Source == null)
            return null;
        var source = Source as BitmapSource;
        if (source == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Need BitmapSource");
        if (source.Format != PixelFormats.Bgra32)
            throw new NotSupportedException("Need 32-bit pixel format with alpha channel");

        // Get the pixel of the source that was hit
        var x = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X / ActualWidth * source.PixelWidth);
        var y = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y / ActualHeight * source.PixelHeight);

        var pixel = new byte[4];
        source.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixel, 4, 0);

        if (pixel[3] < transparentAlpha)
            return null;

        return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
    }
}
```

(Код украден с благодарностью украден [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4801434/276994).)

Отлично, попробуем использовать. На клик навесим наш обработчик, а на `IsMouseOver` добавим glow-эффект через стиль.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="ImageWithGlow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect
                            ShadowDepth="0" Color="White"
                            Opacity="0.8" BlurRadius="8"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Background="Red">
    <local:OpaqueClickableImage
        Source="transparentheart.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageWithGlow}"
        MouseLeftButtonDown="OnImageClick"/>
</Grid>
```

(Я специально нарисовал [картинку с сердечком](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFKPT.png), можно использовать на 8-ое марта.)

Результат (на второй анимации для примера несколько одинаковых картинок рядом):

[image: мимими!]
[image: двойное мимими!]

Comment: а несколько независимых сердечек может быть?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну да. Просто несколько `Image`'ей.

Comment: то есть они не будут перекрываться если налазить на друг друга будут?

Comment: @Grundy: Добавил вторую картинку в ответ.

Comment: @VladD, как объявить префикс local?

Comment: @АнтонБурак: Как-нибудь так: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:тут_полное_название_вашего_namespace"`, рядом с `xmlns:x="..."`.